# Sql Parser With Engine

Tags: java, sql

I need parser on java that parse SQL and return it as some structure. This structure must have some binding point to what I can bind low level reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need to did a little deeper than @Adamski's [Zql](http://www.gibello.com/code/zql/), take a look at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), which has grammars for most flavors of SQL.

Comment: And where I can get an engine that handles: joins, group by, etc? Zql, Antlr are only parsers.

Comment: Have you looked at Apache Derby?

Comment: @merin: what do you mean by 'handles'?  Do you want to execute the SQL in some way or just get it into some tree structure?  It's been a while since I used ANTLR but from memory it will generate an AST that can optionally contain custom nodes.

Comment: Ya, you right: I want execute SQL, but low level is written by me. I have Paradox db, but my jdbc driver it's a pure java code and it's reads the file structure.
I want to end my paradox jdbc driver by supporting of SQL.

Comment: @merin: so if I remember rightly Paradox doesn't support SQL and so what you want to do is process a SQL statement in order to retrieve data from a Paradox DB, right?  This is considerably more complicated that simply parsing the SQL, you need to generate, optimize and execute a *query plan*.  This first step will be the parsing (which ANTLR will help with) but as I'm not familiar with Paradox I can't really tell you much more than that, other than it'll be quite a task.  I'd suggest your time would be better spent getting the data into a modern DB that already supports SQL.

Comment: You right, but customer has Paradox DB :-( And I have to integrate with this DB.:-(((( I have already wrote jdbc driver which read paradox files in low level. Now my driver supports only simple SQL queries.

Comment: Good luck with that.  I'd be tempted to write some code that keeps a Hypersonic DB (or similar) in sync with the Paradox DB, using the SQL engine provided.

Answer (score 0):

How about parse sql and then generate [XML output with query structure information](http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/generate-internal-query-parse-tree-in-xml-for-further-processing/). then you can use this XML which including SQL parse tree for further investigation.